# Not able to find Finder app icon in the list of apps?

Tags: macos, finder

I am new to Apple computers (I have used Windows) and I do not have much experience.

I know that Finder is app like other apps and is Mac alternative to Windows Explorer. I am unable to find the Finder icon in list of all apps.

Why is that so?

Comment: Asking why Apple does something is off topic, so I’ll close this to new answers. No harm in keeping it up and closed. If you have a practical question where given that Apple made this implementation, how you do something else, that’s on topic as an edit or new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### This is by design

[Finder](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201732) is the default graphical file manager that comes pre-installed with macOS. It gets launched automatically for you as soon as you login, and keeps running throughout your login session.

While Finder is a graphical app, like many others that comes pre-installed, and the ones that can be installed on your Mac, macOS does not provide a user visible app icon (app bundle) for it in the list of apps. (Power users can, thought access the Finder.app bundle here: `/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app`).

That's the reason why you cannot see Finder.app icon either in the Applications folder, or in Launchpad (the grid of icons that's displayed when you press the F4 key on your keybaord or the Launchpad icon on your MacBook's Touch Bar).

Finder icon is **always** displayed in the macOS Dock, which can be found in the bottom of the screen (the Dock can be set to be placed in Left or Right side of the screen too, and can also be set to auto-hide). So, to access the Finder app, you can click on the Finder icon displayed in the Dock.

If you wish to re-lauch (quit and launch) the Finder app, you can do so by going to  Menu → Force Quit... (or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Escape</kbd>), select the entry corresponding to Fidner, and click on the **Relaunch** button.

[image: macOS Force Quit Applications windows]